# How to faster renew ImageView by Bitmap

Tags: android, imageview

I want to renew imageView fastly. My code is that ImageView is changed every 3 colors. It operates correctly. but very slow. I want to faster operate the code. what should i do? This is my code.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ImageView img;
int[] arr = new int[300];
int colorArr[] = {Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN, Color.RED};
char color = 0;
DisplayMetrics dm;
Bitmap bit;
int x = 1, y = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

    bit = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 400, RGB_565);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 300; i++)
        arr[i] = colorArr[color%3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j < 400; j++)
           bit.setPixel(i,j, Color.WHITE);
    }

    img.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bit.setPixels(arr, 0, 300, 0, y++, 300,1);
                img.setImageBitmap(bit);
                img.post(this);

                if(y == 400){

                    color++;
                    for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
                        arr[i] = colorArr[color%3];
                    y = 0;
                }

            }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: instead of `setPixel` for each pixel just use `Canvas` api like `Canvas#drawRect`, `Canvas#drawPaint`, `Canvas#drawColor` etc

Comment: That is good way. But I want to access each pixel in picture. Is there a way draw a pixel?

Comment: what you mean "each pixel"? what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: I want to draw pixel that is sended by raspberry pi3.

Comment: so try `Bitmap#getPixels()` / `Bitmap#setPixels()`

Comment: But, I want to get pixel by bluetooth. so i can't use getPixels method.

Comment: bluetooth? what bluetooth? what do you want to do with your `ImageView`? whats your goal?

Comment: I will send to android video pixels read by raspberry pi3 cam. and i will show them in image view